# How to de-structure an enum values in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, enums, destructure

I have an enum in typescript like below:

```js
export enum XMPPElementName {
  state = "state",
  presence = "presence",
  iq = "iq",
  unreadCount = "uc",
  otherUserUnreadCount = "ouc",
  sequenceID = "si",
  lastSequenceID = "lsi",
  timeStamp = "t",
  body = "body",
  message = "message"
}
```

And wants to de-structure its value, How can we do this in Typescript?

```
const { uc, ouc, msg, lsi, si, t, body } =  XMPPElementName;
```

## update

As @amadan [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548582/12666332), we can use `Assigning to new variable names` as in Mozilla doc say [Destructuring_assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548439/12666332), like below:

#### Assigning to new variable names

A property can be unpacked from an object and assigned to a variable with a different name than the object property.

```js
const o = {p: 42, q: true};
const {p: foo, q: bar} = o;
 
console.log(foo); // 42 
console.log(bar); // true
```

And the method is very good to solve this problem, but if  you need to access all items without the need to explicitly define them, you can either on of these two mentiond [tag1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548582/12666332) [tag2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548439/12666332)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> const { uc, ouc, msg, lsi, si, t, body } =  XMPPElementName;
> ```

This doesn't work because `XMPPElementName` doesn't have an element named `uc` (and equivalently for others). If you explicitly name your keys, it will work:

```
  const {
    unreadCount: uc,
    otherUserUnreadCount: ouc,
    message: msg,
    lastSequenceID: lsi,
    sequenceID: si,
    timeStamp: t,
    body: body,
  } = XMPPElementName;
```

it will work. Alternately, you can just use variables with names that are equal to the keys, not the values:

```
  const {
    unreadCount,
    otherUserUnreadCount,
    message,
    lastSequenceID,
    sequenceID,
    timeStamp,
    body,
  } = XMPPElementName;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want an enum value-to-value map. Like you've said enum in JS is just a POJO. You can create a utility type to help generate the correct type.

```
type EnumValueMap<T extends { [k: string]: string }> = { [K in T[keyof T]]: K }

function convertEnumValuesToObject<T extends { [k: string]: string }>(enumerable: T): EnumValueMap<T> {
  return (Object as any).fromEntries(Object.values(enumerable).map(v => [v, v]))
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAGgsgBQQUQDbAqALgOQIaZQDeAsAFBRQDOWeWwUAvFAEQ13AsA05lADgCdgVUAGMGzFoOFjOPClACWARyasV3XlDAgheACYBhAPY6salmFGaFxrAAtgAgKoiXu4AZNmLp6-MoRZTBZAEkAEQsqRRtKVDwaAGVgYLDIyVRo2KgsRUxE2gg+CyxsgCNjfQBPCwrq7MwqKjwAcwlWRua2lnIAX3JyLCq+BmRwCAA1PFQQuDw+AB4AFShgAA96EH0qYigAbQBrAC5qLAFFEBaAXROac8uoXoA+NSJ9gGklECglw+Aq4wAMx+VxuUE+-TI5EBOlEuWM31ECIAbk4sGNIFMZsIlsYAPJlABWwDhy1WG1A212h1uZwu11p9xajyeAApQJAnHgyugTksAJQnDGTaazebLF6kBRCLBgATfVkE4lwqAJVUgKr8gB0gIExggYzpwkVRJJWC1yNFxo5mAE3PQ2og81ZyKYLz2yK4UGRV35-L6AzISJANF2Vi9fi9mUUXuiXqwXrqNV6amDqIE6PGWJCVFxSrNrPgSDQGGw+Ew-IA3ORg1RjOgtahjC1WeGoJGoNHYzGconKprK0A)

Answer (score 1):

As we know, in typescript an enum is like a plain old javascript object(at-least what the playground js-output is showing or the log showing):

[image]

one way is using a function which generates a new object with `{value:value}` structure like below:

```js
export function convertEnumValuesToObject<T>(enumObj: T): { [index: string]: T[keyof T] } {
  const enum_values = Object.values(enumObj);
  return Object.assign({}, ...enum_values.map(_ => ({ [_]: _ })));
}

  const { uc, ouc, msg, lsi, si, t, body } = convertEnumValuesToObject(
      XMPPElementName
    );
```

It would be great to see answers in typescript?

Comment: typescript version added, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for anyone looking for a quick and easy answer - yes you can (at least as of now). This works for enums with and without assigned values as far as I can tell.

```
enum MyEnum {
  One,
  Two,
  Three
}

const { One, Two, Three } = myEnum;

console.log({ One, Two, Three }) // {One: 0, Two: 1, Three: 2}

enum Status {
   None = '',
   Created = 'CREATED',
   Completed = 'COMPLETED',
   Failed = 'FAILED',
}

const { None, Created, Completed, Failed } = Status;

console.log(None, Created, Completed, Failed) // '', 'CREATED', 'COMPLETED, 'FAILED'
```

Please write me back if I'm wrong or you found any weirdness when testing yourself.